# How to output only true? (find)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to find an element from the database that is equal to **"newUser"**, the total number of elements in the database is 2, why do I get **true** first and then **false**? After all, the find method should search for only one element? How to make it display only true?

```
const userSignInFunc = (user, services) => dispatch => {
    const newUser = [{
        login: user.login.value, 
        password: user.password.value
    }];
    services.getDataUsers(res => res.map(e => { // database

        const find = newUser.find(elem => elem.login === e.user.login && elem.password === e.user.password);
        console.log(!!find) // true & false

        if(find) {
            dispatch(userSignin(e.id));
        } else {
            dispatch(userSignInError(true));
        };
        return false;
    }));
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hggrR.png)

Comment: if `.getDataUsers()` returns ALL users in your database (2 currently), then your `newUser.find()` is going to run twice, since you're `.map()`ing over two results.. hence 2 console logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` method instead of map:

```
const newUser = {
  login: 'user_login', 
  password: 'user_password'
};

services.getDataUsers(users => {
  const user = users.find(user => newUser.login === user.login && 
  newUser.password === user.password)

  if(user) {
    dispatch(userSignin(user.id));
  } else {
    dispatch(userSignInError(true));
  };
});
```

Comment: `const users = services.getDataUsers()`

Comment: You can`t return values from callback function